# Has anybody faced with cases, when AggregateException.InnerExceptions.Count > 1?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I'm wondering, has anybody faced with cases, when `AggregateException.InnerExceptions.Count` > 1?

E.g., TPL wraps exception, that was raised in task body, in `AggregateException`. But I never saw situations, when there was more than one inner exception.

How this can be achieved with TPL?
How this can be achieved with *any* FCL (or another widely used library) classes (samples will be useful)?

I know, that there's *possibility* to build such instance of `AggregateException`, but the question is about a practice. I'm asking about this, because I want to understand, what is the best way to handle `AggregateException`.

Comment: One example: If you have a parent Task that creates one or more child Tasks (that are set to "attached to parent"), then children task and the parent task could throw an exception and in those cases you'll end up with more than on exception in the AggregateException returned from the parent task.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The typical case is when  a task is dependent on multiple tasks, and more than one of those tasks throw exceptions. For example:

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => { throw new Exception(); } );
var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => Console.WriteLine("Innocuous") );
var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => { throw new Exception(); } );

// Output: 2
var t4 = Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3)
             .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Exception.InnerExceptions.Count), 
                           TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Answer (score 2):

As Ani has said these `AggregateExceptions` can be created via multiple successive `Task`s using continuations to observer the exceptions.

```
Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new Exception(); });
Task t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new Exception(); });
Task t3 = Task.WhenAll(t1, t2)
    .ContinueWith(t => t.Exception.InnerExceptions.Count(), 
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Typically you would handle the `AggregateException` within a continuation. A continuation can find out if an exception was thrown by the antecedent `Task` by the antecedent task's exception property. The following prints the results of a `NullReferenceException` to the console

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => { throw null; });
Task task2 = task1.ContinueWith (ant => Console.Write(ant.Exception());
```

If `task1` throws an exception and this exception is not captured/queried by the continuation it is considered unhandled and the application dies. With continuations it is enough to establish the result of the task via the `Status` keyword

```
asyncTask.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    // Check task status.
    switch (task.Status)
    {
        // Handle any exceptions to prevent UnobservedTaskException.             
        case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
            if (asyncTask.Result)
            {
                // Do stuff...
            }
            break;
        case TaskStatus.Faulted:
            if (task.Exception != null)
                mainForm.progressRightLabelText = task.Exception.Flatten().Message;
            else
                mainForm.progressRightLabelText = "Operation failed!";
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Where in the above I only expect a single exception - to ensure this is the case I can call [`Flatten()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.flatten.aspx). If you are expecting other types of exceptions you can iterate through the `InnerException`s as required.

I hope this helps.